# MySQL take a range of values based on a column of descending numbers, and then randomize that range

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble implementing in my code what should be a simple query. I'm trying to take a range of values, say numbered sequentially 1-20 in a column named front_weight and then randomize that query by that column. So far what I've come up with is:

```
$sql_rand_limit_range = "SELECT * FROM posts 
                         WHERE active='y' 
                         AND front_weight > 0 
                         AND front_weight 
                         IN (SELECT front_weight 
                         FROM posts ORDER BY front_weight DESC LIMIT 0, 20) 
                         ORDER BY RAND()";
```

I get this error:

```
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

I am running MySQL Version 5.1 by the way. I then try to monkey around with the query a little bit trying something like this which in my eyes should work:

```
$sql_rand_limit_range = "SELECT * FROM posts 
                         WHERE active='y' 
                         AND front_weight > 0
                         ORDER BY RAND() front_weight DESC
                         LIMIT 0, 20";


$sql_rand_limit_range = "SELECT * FROM posts 
                         WHERE active='y' 
                         AND front_weight > 0
                         ORDER BY front_weight DESC
                         LIMIT 0, 20 
                         RAND()";
```

But you SQL ninjas can see how far that got me. Any ideas or will I have to do something a little bit more drastic using Php code like randomizing mysqli_fetch_array?

EDIT: I'm getting alot of exotic queries to return something like 15,12,3,17,9,5,11...... I just want to return rows 1-20 in a column randomized. Basically I'm trying to ask in sql parlance how to get this:

```
 ORDER BY front_weight DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

to play nice with this:

```
 ORDER BY RAND()
```

I really hope I don't need joins and pseudo-tables, but if I do, so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for all your help. After continuing to fiddle with it some more I found the right query for my needs:

```
$sql_rand_limit_range = "SELECT * FROM posts 
                         WHERE active='y' 
                         AND front_weight BETWEEN 1 AND 20 
                         ORDER BY RAND()";
```

Good old BETWEEN, hardly used but never truly forgotten!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$sql_rand_limit_range = "SELECT * FROM posts 
                         WHERE active='y' 
                         AND front_weight > 0 
                         AND front_weight 
                         IN (SELECT front_weight 
                         FROM posts ORDER BY front_weight DESC) 
                         ORDER BY RAND  LIMIT 0, 20";
```

Comment: Yeah, that was one of my many solutions before posting this question here. The problem is I'm not getting a randomized version of 1-20. With this query I'm getting a randomized version of every row in the column front_weight. I'm looking for something like 15,1,7,12,19,3,6......

Answer (score 0):

Try using `INNER JOIN` instead of `IN`

```
$sql_rand_limit_range = "SELECT p1.* FROM posts p1
                         INNER JOIN
                            (SELECT front_weight 
                             FROM posts ORDER BY front_weight DESC LIMIT 0, 20) as p2
                         ON p1.front_weight = p2.front_weight
                         WHERE p1.active='y' 
                         AND p1.front_weight > 0
                         ORDER BY RAND()";
```

---

According to your comments you are wanting a simplified version. Then try

```
$sql_rand_limit_range = "SELECT * FROM posts
                         WHERE active='y'
                         AND front_weight BETWEEN 1 AND 20
                         ORDER BY RAND()";
```

Comment: Do the WHERE conditions need to be inside the nested query to ensure that 20 results are given?

Comment: I get "Column 'front_weight' in where clause is ambiguous". You got a query that's simpler than this?  I'm just looking for a return query like 15,1,7,12,19,3,6......

Comment: It should have been `WHERE p1.active='y' AND p1.front_weight > 0`. Updated the answer.

Comment: @user3423909 So you just want to randomize the first 20? If so, why do you have `ORDER BY front_weight DESC` in your subquery?

Comment: Yeah, I'm still getting values outside of 1-20 using this query. Yeah, I just want to randomize first 20, preferably without inner joins and pseudo-tables if possible.

Comment: So you are just wanting `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE front_weight BETWEEN 1 AND 20 ORDER BY RAND()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a RIGHT JOIN

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts 
RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT front_weight FROM posts WHERE active='y' AND front_weight > 0 DESC LIMIT 0,20) randomizer
ON posts.front_weight = randomizer.front_weight
ORDER BY RAND()
```